# How does India tax foreign stipends?

Tags: income-tax, india, tax-exemption

I am a student in India, recently selected for the Google Summer of Code. Google provides a stipend of 5000 USD for successful completion of the project. They also state that this is not [employment](http://www.google-melange.com/gsoc/document/show/gsoc_program/google/gsoc2015/help_page#17._employment). I have heard that such "stipends" are exempt from taxation in India, but 5k USD (over 300k INR) is above the minimum taxable income (which is around 200-250k INR, IIRC). Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: @gitter I haven't approached a professional CA yet, but a few people who have been selected in the past say it's taxable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stipend received for the specific purposes of studies is not taxable. It is not clear from your question as to whether there are any strings attached to the money you receive. If its not for specific purpose, then its taxable as income and tax need to be paid accordingly.

Please consult a CA and he can go through the specifics of your case.

Comment: "strings"... Well, we have to clear evaluations, mid-project and at the end. But yes, it's not for the specific purpose of studies.